# Building the Linux kernel: compute intensive or disk I/O intensive?

Tags: compile, benchmarking, linux-kernel

I am trying to explain some results that I got from a recent benchmarking experiment. For that I need to know whether compiling the Linux kernel is a compute intensive task or a disk I/O intensive task. A justification too would be very helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's both compute and disk intensive! You'll get some stats from [kcbench](http://linux.die.net/man/1/kcbench), which is available for most distros. Beyond that, it depends what you are trying to observe and prove.

Comment: I am not sure how these stats explain that it is both compute and disk intensive. I am trying to benchmark the performance of various virtual machines (kvm-qemu , vmplayer)

Comment: Ah, that's helpful info. You might find some more useful stuff in this over at Serverfault: http://serverfault.com/questions/26932/best-way-to-benchmark-linux-virtualization-solutions